# Feature detection for the vector-effect property in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, browser-feature-detection

SVG Tiny 1.2 [defines a property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke) called `vector-effect`.

```
<path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="2"></path>
```

With the above path, the stroke width will always be 2 pixels, even if the element gets scaled (due to a `transform` on a parent `g` element, for example).

This property seems to work in most of the SVG-supporting browsers, **but not in IE9 and IE10**.

Is there any way to feature-detect this property?

Comment: I believe a modernizr test for this can be made if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Firefox and IE 9.

```
  <script>
    var elm = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    if (elm.style.vectorEffect != undefined) {
      alert("Supported");
    } else {
      alert("Not Supported");
    }
  </script>
```

Alternatively you could try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#testprop). Something like this I suppose.

```
Modernizr.testProp('vectorEffect')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not to create an element.

```
if (document.documentElement.style.vectorEffect === undefined) {
  alert("Not Supported");
} else {
  alert("Supported");
}
```